# Maximized and centered square div

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want my page divided and three parts (div).

The middle div must be square and take all available space.

The side divs must take the remaining space equally on left and right or top and bottom, independently of their contents.

I used flex along with
width: 100vmin
height: 100vmin

But I have to change flex-direction in a window resize event handler.

Is it possible to do it without JavaScript ?

```js
// Set the flex direction according to current size
var flexRow = (window.innerWidth >= window.innerHeight);
document.getElementById("main").style.flexDirection = flexRow ? "row" : "column";

// Change the flex direction on window resize
window.addEventListener(
 "resize",
 function() {
  if (flexRow != (window.innerWidth >= window.innerHeight)) {
   flexRow = !flexRow;
   document.getElementById("main").style.flexDirection = flexRow ? "row" : "column";
  }
 }
);
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
 position: absolute;
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.pan-side {
 background-color: #999999;
 flex: 1 1 0;
 min-width: 0;
 min-height: 0;
 padding: 1%;
}

#pan-main {
 width: 100vmin;
 height: 100vmin;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div id="main">
  <div id="pan-side1" class="pan-side"></div>
  <div id="pan-main"></div>
  <div id="pan-side2" class="pan-side">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please post the code you've tried. A working demo (e.g., jsfiddle.net) would be helpful also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use media queries like this:

```
  .flex {flex-direction:column;}

@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
  .flex {flex-direction:row;}
}
```

See [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4s0zbkv6/)

Comment: Yes! It seems to do exactly what I want. Thanks

Comment: Be sure to be cautious with the `orientation` media feature. All it is doing is checking the viewport width against the height. This can lead to situations where extreme viewport dimensions, while still technically `portrait` or `landscape` orientations, can break your layout.

Comment: @briceshatzer Why would it break? Out of interest, can you make an example, or is there more info about such an issue somewhere?

Comment: It was meant to be more of a note about using the orientation media feature in general. In this exact situation, it would't.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.main');
if(el.scrollHeight< window.innerHeight){  document.querySelector('.container').style.flexDirection = "column"
}
```

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.main{
  background-color:blue;
  width:100vmin; 
  height: 100vmin;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="alt"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
  <div class="alt"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: that´s almost what I did but I want it without javascript